# Why can't I uninstall FTP service?

Tags: ftp, uninstall, windows-server-2016

I need to uninstall the FTP service, but I can't deselect the checkbox:

[image]

Why is this? I've stopped a bunch of services. All FTP sites are stopped.

Answer (score 6):

From the looks of things you are trying to use the Add Roles and Features wizard to remove the role services, instead you will need to use the Remove Roles and Features wizard.

Once selected the Remove Roles and Features wizard will allow you to remove check boxes next to currently installed features that you no longer desire to be installed.

I have added pictures below to show the process.

Add Roles and Features wizard:
[image]

Accessing the Removal wizard:
[image]

Remove Roles and Features wizard:
[image]